# How to properly install ubuntu so it will boot on laptops designed for Windows10?

Tags: 14.04, boot, toshiba-satellite

I'm still struggling to boot my freshly installed Ubuntu 14 on my Toshiba Satelite Laptop. Previously there was Windows 10 on this laptop preinstalled. I formatted the hard drive and installed Ubuntu, but it won't boot... I can only use my computer from Live-USB Ubuntu... Please help me.

PS: I am NOT interested in dual-boot! I do not want to have any Microsoft products on my laptop. I just want to be able to run this machine with Ubuntu or perhaps other Linux distro if they are easier to boot properly.

PS2: I did disable secure boot!

Comment: You might need to turn Secure Boot off in the BIOS settings.

Comment: That W10 runs on a notebook is not a criterium for Linux to run on a notebook. Hardware compatibility is. Linux will have trouble installing on the newest hardware; it always takes a bit of time to get the drivers created (since someone will have to buy the hardware and then create them).  3 things: disable secure boot, make sure of UEFI, if GRUB shows and installer crashes to a black screen start boot with "nomodeset" (grub -> f6).

Comment: I turned secure boot off.

Comment: "make sure of UEFI, if GRUB shows and installer crashes to a black screen start boot with "nomodeset" (grub -> f6)." Sorry, I don't understand this part?

Comment: Try installing Ubuntu Desktop 15.10 - it will have all the required drivers for your new laptop. Plus it's easy to upgrade to 16.04 LTS release coming in less than 2 months.

Answer (score -1):

I would install the Ubuntu 16.04 seeing it will be here in just a few weeks it will save you some time later.

Your best bet maybe booting from a USB drive if your machine is older

I'm not sure what specs you have on that machine but it will help us help you better.

Comment: This is fairly new machine. It was bought on December 2015.
Here are parameters: AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics × 4

Comment: What process did you use to burn the IS0 file on? I'm just assuming you had ether a CD or USB, drive? This tutorial might help you accomplish the installation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Comment: Rob G: I installed Ubuntu on USB flashdrive using pendrivelinux (from pendrivelinux.com), while still running Windows 10.